# PowerQuery - merge column with underlying nodes

Tags: json, powerquery

I have JSON with repeatable balances node - see part of it below. I want to move it to Excel via PowerQuery.

```
  "balances": {
    "ETH": {
      "currency": "ETH",
      "total": "161",
      "withdrawing": "40",
    }
  },      
  
  "balances": {
    "BTC": {
      "currency": "BTC",
      "total": "162",
      "withdrawing": "10",
    }
  }
```

The problem is that because of the different names of nodes (ETH, BTC etc.) Excel is creating separate columns for them: ETH.currency, BTC.currency etc. I want to have one currency column, one total column etc. though. How to achieve that?

I tried to merge ETH and BTC columns before expanding them, but because underlying data isnt string I get errors in PowerQuery.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide details with sample data **posted as text** (that reproduces your problem) and examples of your code trying to solve it. Take a look at Help for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add an index, then right click that column and unpivot the other columns.